# SSRS check if date value is greater than given date and hide the textbox

Tags: reporting-services

Hello all I am writing the following condition to hide the textbox based on a condition but some how it is not working

```
<Hidden>=IIF(Format(Fields!VisitDt.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")>= Format("2022-01-08","MM/dd/yyyy"),True,False)</Hidden>
```

So what should be the correct way to do this can some one let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `VisitDt` is actually a date field then you can do something like

```
=IIF(Fields!VisitDt.Value >= DATESERIAL(2022, 1, 8) , True, False)
```

You could actually simply if further as the `Hidden` property only requires an expression that evaluates to `True` or `False` so you could simply use

```
=Fields!VisitDt.Value >= DATESERIAL(2022, 1, 8)
```

There is no need for the `IIF`

Comment: K my visitdt will be in mm/dd/yyyy format will `DATESERIAL(2022, 1, 8)` satisfy that

Comment: Here is the RDL I am trying out https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EJhRuPVHNRAXjedWP4x9PgvJy-8d_ncx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What I feel is when the value is present the text box is not hidden

Comment: Here is the other one where I am seeing true on the label as per the condition but some how the visibility part is not working https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iNieoq_e_cHYjr4Q_C1qkBf2Dmc5a_Sw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What data type is VisitDt? Ignore the formatting, it's the datatype that is important. If it is `Date` or `DateTime` then my answer will work. If it is `varchar` or some other text datatype then it will be cast/converted to a date type first.

Comment: it is datetime only

Comment: in that case my answer should work